What would be a good objective function to tune a PID controller in a 6 DOF robot manipulator?
As stated above, I am currently trying to tune the PID in a controller for a robot arm (the input of the plant is torque, and the output is its state).
I first practiced with a single joint (1 DOF, a simple vertical pendulum), and good nice results using this objective function:
$$
J= \sum_{k=1}^{N} \left|(e_{position})_{k}\right| \Delta{t}
$$
Where $N$ corresponds to the last iteration before ending the simulation.
But there was a problem. I noticed that there were very little oscillations in steady state and gave some weight to the velocity error to flatten the plot:
$$
J= \sum_{k=1}^{N} \left|(e_{position})_{k}\right| \Delta{t}+0.5\sum_{k=1}^{N} \left|(e_{velocity})_{k}\right| \Delta{t}
$$
I set the weight in the velocity error to 0.5 because my priority is still doing a good trajectory tracking (or angle tracking in this case for 1 DOF).
The results improved, but I felt that what I did was just an arbitrary heuristic that could not neccesarily yield good results for a multiple DOF robot arm (MIMO system).
What should I do in that case?
Thanks in advance.
PD: The proportional, derivative and integral gain matrices should each have different values in their diagonals (decentralized joint control) or the same escalar value (centralized joint control)? i.e.:
$diag(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ or $xI$, where $I$ is the identity matrix and $x$ some scalar value. I think the first approach would have a high computational cost, so a suggestion is well received.
